# jQuery $.when done doesn't work for ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a selectbox, which's content and itself get changed with ajax.
I want to change the content with ajax, after it loaded, I want to change the selected option as "test_type".
When I get the data with ajax and change the #type_select_div's content with the new selectbox, it gets loaded, I can see the options but, selected option can't be changed by jquery. (you'll see as test2 below)
But instead of using ajax, if I give the content (which is exactly same with the ajax response), it works perfectly. (you'll see as test1 below)

I couldn't find what I am doing wrong.

HTML part:

```
<div id="type_select_div">
<select id="formElementTypeName" name="formElementTypeName" class="form-control ">
</select>
</div>
<button onclick="loadAndChange()">load and change</button>
```

javascript part:

```
function loadTypes(){
/* test1: works */
var msg='<select class="form-control" name="formElementTypeName" id="formElementTypeName">'
+'<option value="type1">type1</option>'
+'<option value="test_type">test_type</option>'
+'</select>';
$('#type_select_div').html(msg);
/* end of test1*/

/* test2: doesn't work */
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_actions.php",
    success: function(msg){
        $('#type_select_div').html(msg);
    }
});
/* end of test2 */
}

function loadAndChange(){
  $.when(loadTypes()).done(function () {
    $('select[name="formElementTypeName"]').find('option[value="test_type"]').attr("selected",true)
  });
}
```

Comment: returns promise interface from function `return $.ajax(...)` and please use on recent jquery version `.prop("selected",true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the `Deferred` from `loadTypes()`:

```
function loadTypes(){
    var msg='<select class="form-control" name="formElementTypeName" id="formElementTypeName">'
        +'<option value="type1">type1</option>'
        +'<option value="test_type">test_type</option>'
        +'</select>';
    $('#type_select_div').html(msg);

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_actions.php",
        success: function(msg){
            $('#type_select_div').html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the result of the `$.ajax` call to your method so that jQuery knows it is a promise:

```
function loadTypes(){
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_actions.php",
        success: function(msg){
            $('#type_select_div').html(msg);
        }
    });
}

function loadAndChange(){
  $.when(loadTypes()).done(function () {
        $('select[name="formElementTypeName"]').find('option[value="test_type"]').attr("selected",true)
  });
}
```